# Which was Nine's betrayal to Tomura Shigaraki?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the BNHA wikia it's mentioned that Nine betrayed Tomura. But I didnt realize any of this during the movie. Which was Nine's betrayal to Tomura Shigaraki?

Comment: Can you include a link to the specific page in wikia where you read this?

Answer (score -1):

That's incorrect and it's actually the other way around, Towards the end of the movie we see tomura kill nine, so no, nine didn't betray anyone.

Comment: This does not show that Nine didn't betray Tomura who could have killed him because of a betrayal.